# Obtaining cdf from a pdf containing absolute value and sign function

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to calculate the cdf of the following pdf:

$f(y|\mu, \sigma, k, \lambda) = \frac{C}{\sigma} exp(-\frac{1}{[1+sign(y-\mu+\delta\sigma)\lambda]^k \theta^k \sigma^k}|y-\mu+\delta\sigma|^k),$

where $C=\frac{k}{2\theta}\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{k} \right)^{-1}$, $\theta = \Gamma \left( \frac{1}{k} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma \left( \frac{3}{k} \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} S(\lambda)^{-1}$, $\delta = 2\lambda A S(\lambda)^{-1}$, $\delta = 2\lambda A S(\lambda)^{-1}$.

$y-\mu+\delta\sigma$ is the mode of the variable $y$.

So to calculate the cdf I need to solve $\int^{x}_{-\infty} f(y)dy$.

As this pdf contains both absolute value and the $sign$ function I assume I need to split the integral over a few cases. Could you please show me the first steps of solving this integral? I am confused how to choose those intervals for splitting the integral.

Comment: this looks like integrating $exp(-x^k)$, and for the $k=2$ case, it's known there is no closed form http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18286/why-the-cdf-for-the-normal-distribution-can-not-be-expressed-as-a-closed-form-fu

Comment: I see. I apply restrictions that $k > 0$. Is there a relatively simple way to obtain random numbers coming from this distribution? Perhaps some algorithm that after some modifications will yield the desired results.

Comment: Metropolis-hastings algorithm comes to mind